# Ruby, что не так с кодом? и что на счет лаконичности и правильности

Tags: ruby

Изучаю Ruby. Решил написать консольную программку "Компьютер выбирает рандомное число, а пользователь должен его угадать с трёх попыток."
Но программа работает не верно, Ограничение по попыткам не работает. То ли не плюсует, то ли что. Т.к больше трех попыток, а в выигрыше вывод что угадал с 1 попытки.

```
puts "Приветствуем вас. Компьютер загадал число от 1 до 7, попробуйте его угадать с 3-ёх попыток."
chislo_komp = rand(7)

chislo_user = nil
popitka = 0

while chislo_user != chislo_komp
  puts "Введите число: "
  chislo_user = gets.chomp.to_i
  if chislo_user != chislo_komp && popitka <=3
    puts "Введите число: "
    chislo_user = gets.chomp.to_i
    popitka = popitka+1
  elsif chislo_user == chislo_komp
    puts "Урааа, вы выиграли!"
    puts "Вы угадали число с " + popitka.to_s + " раза."
  elsif popitka > 3
    puts "Сожалеем, но ваши попытки исчерпаны. Вы проиграли."
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Т.к. есть как минимум два условия выхода из цикла, я бы воспользовался `loop` с двумя `break`, что позволит избавиться от переменной `guessed`. Возьму за основу код @m0nhawk:

```
puts "Приветствуем вас. Компьютер загадал число от 1 до 7, попробуйте его угадать с трех попыток."

computer_choice = rand(7)

step = 1
loop 
  puts "Введите число: "
  user_choice = gets.chomp.to_i
  if computer_choice == user_choice
    puts "Урааа, вы выиграли!"
    puts "Вы угадали число с " + step.to_s + " раза."
    break
  end
  if 3 < step += 1
    puts "Сожалеем, но ваши попытки исчерпаны. Вы проиграли."
    break
  end
end
```

Вообще все переменные нужно хранить как можно глубже и не класть в верхние области видимости без необходимости. Поэтому переменную `step` я бы положил внутрь как переменную цикла `times{ |step| }` вместо `loop{}`, но тогда прерывание цикла через `if 3 < step` выглядело бы неуклюжим, и пришлось бы снова вынести наружу `guessed`. И раз уж приходится что-то выносить наружу, пусть это останется переменная `step`, т.к она информативней.

Условия выхода лучше располагать в начале тела цикла, чтобы как можно дольше придерживаться *цикла с предусловием* -- это не Ruby-совет, а общий. А при перемещении `step += 1` в начало тела цикла следует обратить внимание на начальное значение `step` -- мы должны снизить его до 0.

"3-ёх" -- так лучше не писать (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_99). Вместо `.chomp` я бы воспользовался `.strip`, чтобы обрезать и передние пробельные символы. Переменная `user_choice` в принципе не нужна вне цикла игры, потому как меняется от шага к шагу, поэтому я бы ее вообще убрал, но оставлю в коде на всякий случай. Использование интерполяции `#{}` позволяет не делать `.to_s`, а т.к. не сработавший `if` возвращает `nil`, то `nil.to_s` оставит за собой пустую строку, поэтому см. как можно сделать опциональное окончание -а.

```
puts "Приветствуем вас. Компьютер загадал число от 1 до 7, попробуйте его угадать с трех попыток."

computer_choice = rand(7)

step = 0
loop 
  if 3 < step += 1
    puts "Сожалеем, но ваши попытки исчерпаны. Вы проиграли."
    break
  end
  puts "Введите число: "
  if computer_choice == user_choice = gets.chomp.to_i
    puts "Урааа, вы выиграли!"
    puts "Вы угадали число с #{step} раз#{"a" if step == 1}."
    break
  end
end
```